# How to call OpenSSL methods in Java?

Tags: java, android, openssl, java-native-interface

I have to call openssl methods in java e.g android.external.openssl.crypto.pkcs7.PKCS7_encrypt() method. I found that there is no JNI implementation for this. So I have to write JNI layer. 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

So I learned basic JNI. I found that If I want to call a method e.g search() in java, then method definition in C will be like  Java_packageNameOfJavaFile_JavaClassName_method(). Mehotd name says that c/c++ library implementation has to be done after creating header file(*.h file) for native method.

My confusion is If I want to use inbuild library(openssl library) those method doesn't include naming convension as mentioned above, then how should I call those methods in Java.

Comment: "How to call OpenSSL methods in Java?" - DON'T! use another crypto library.

Comment: Why? There's plenty of crypto built into Java. You probably don't need anything external, and if you do it will probably be found in BouncyCastle.

Comment: Use `javah` to create the Java-mangled names.

Comment: EJP - he may need FIPS. As far as I know, none of the free Java crypto libraries provide it. The ones that do are not free and may be infiltrated by US spy agencies (RSA Data Security's BSAFE).

Comment: @jww He may or he may not. It's up to him to tell us. I'm not much interested in guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you don't call an existing library from Java using JNI; You create a new shared library that exports JNI-compatible functions that happen to use whatever libraries you need to implement them.

To use JNI, you:

1. decide on a natural, Java-centric model (classes and methods) for the functionality you need
2. add `native` to the declaration of the methods
3. compile the .java files to .class files using `javac`
4. run `javah` on the classes, passing a classpath, which is similar to running `java`
5. implement the C functions emitted into the header. (You can use either C or C++ syntax)
6. if a function implementation requires many Java type conversions or other manipulations in JNI code, go back to the Java class and do the manipulations there, moving `native` to a `private` method that is easier to implement in JNI code than the original Java-centric method. (An example of this is string manipulations, where it can be easier for an implementation to consume a Java `String` as a Java `byte[]` with the character set/encoding needed by the libraries you use)

A function implementation usually follows the input-processing-output pattern: converting data from the Java parameters into C/C++ data types, calling a library function for processing and then converting data from C/C++ data structures to the Java return object.

You can also create Java objects, call methods and explicitly throw Java exceptions with JNI code.

And always be mindful that a JNI call can leave a Java exception thrown into the JVM, in which case you need to check and branch in your C/C++ code. When you want to leave the exception as thrown, you should stop calling other JNI functions, clean up and exit the function.

And, of course, all C++ exceptions must be caught and handled appropriately.

---

Alternatives (that actually use JNI under the covers):

1. SWIG
2. JNA, JNAerator

These take the opposite approach: take a (sometimes simplified or annotated) C or C++ header and create code that calls functions defined in it. You then might build up a Java model around it to make it more natural to call in your application code.